# What is the difference between createMock and getMockBuilder in phpUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

For the love of my life I can't figure out the difference between `createMock($type)` and `getMockBuilder($type)`

I am going through the original documentation and there is just a one liner which I didn't understand.

> ... you can use the getMockBuilder($type) method to customize the test double generation using
>   a fluent interface.

If you can provide me an example, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the manual
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

> The createMock($type) and getMockBuilder($type) methods provided by
>   PHPUnit can be used in a test to automatically generate an object that
>   can act as a test double for the specified original type (interface or
>   class name). This test double object can be used in every context
>   where an object of the original type is expected or required.
>
> The **createMock($type)** method immediately returns a test double object
>   for the specified type (interface or class). The creation of this test
>   double is performed using best practice defaults (the __construct()
>   and __clone() methods of the original class are not executed and the
>   arguments passed to a method of the test double will not be cloned.
>
> If these defaults are not what you need then you can use the
>   **getMockBuilder($type)** method to customize the test double generation
>   using a fluent interface.

They are already plenty answers on stack overflow what are fluent interfaces.

Comment: `$mock_service_provider = $this->createMock("\Service\ServiceProvider")->method("getService")->willReturn($service)` isn't this fluent as well? So it is a similarity not a difference. I wanted some concrete differences, I have read the manual, but I am yet to have an epiphany... though nonetheless I am using this very snippet.

Comment: @ChristianM.Raymonds I think it's not fluent. getMockBuilder is useful when you want to create classes on fly ( which doesn't exists in the system ) $this->getMockBuilder('SomeFunnyClassName')->setMethods(array('FunnyMethodName'))->getMock(); For standard testing you want to use createMock

Comment: Well I really appreciate your efforts to help me, but, I guess you misunderstood `fluency`. It has more to do with a DSL kind of an approach, like near-real spoken language affinity. Both `createMock` and `getMockBuilder` are *almost* fluent. But, the part where you said about `creating on the fly` is absolutely what I was looking for. I was testing the methods in the meanwhile and that's exactly what it is. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 89):

**createMock($type)** uses `getMockBuilder()` internally:

```
protected function createMock($originalClassName)
{
    return $this->getMockBuilder($originalClassName)
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->disableOriginalClone()
                ->disableArgumentCloning()
                ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
                ->getMock();
}
```

So the `createMock()` method will return you a mock built with the general best-practice defaults.

But with **getMockBuilder($type)**, you can create a mock with your own requirements.

Comment: I have been using createMock for years and wondering why people are using getMockBuilder instead. Well I am pretty sure their purpose was not "to customize the test double generation using a fluent interface" thanks for this answer