# Symfony - mocking TokenInterface returning object

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have an issue returning correct behaviour when mocking specific object while writing tests in Symfony 5.

My method:

```
public function myTestFunction(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
         }

      ..... 
     }
```

I was trying in my tests like:

```
$this->token = $this->createMock(TokenInterface::class);
$this->token
     ->method('getUser')
     ->willReturn(UserInterface::class);
```

Result does not replicate the behaviour I want to accomplished based on the code I posted.

As I am defining $token as a stub, I am forced to describe every interaction with it, otherwise `PHPUnit`, will return null for every method call.

Answer (score 1):

In your `->willReturn` call you should pass the real object instead of string of the class name. This is what I see wrong in your current code.

So you should create real User class which is an instance of the UserInterface and pass this object into `->willReturn($realUserObject)`.

I think it should help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @SzymonSzymkowiak . I guess something else is the problem as I tried with your proposition and still getting null. I will post another question.

Comment: @yaraw69 you can try to use getMockBuilder, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363086/what-is-the-difference-between-createmock-and-getmockbuilder-in-phpunit

Comment: Tried with that. Still the same. Thanks for trying to help! Can you please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72906473/symfony-testing-vote-gets-null-on-mock-tokeninterface to see my actual problem? Thanks @ SzymonSzymkowiak